# How to override a field value injected by @Value in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection, integration-testing

I have a class with a field injected from a property using `@Value`:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Value(${property.key})
    private String filePath;
    ...
```

My integration tests need to change `filePath` to point at some different files.

I tried using reflection to set it before invoking a method:

```
public class MyClassIT {
    @Autowired MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void testMyClassWithTestFile1 {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myClass, "filePath", "/tests/testfile1.csv");
        myClass.invokeMethod1();
        ...
```

But when the first method gets invoked, the `@Value` injection kicks in and changes the value from what was just set. Could anyone suggest how to resolve this or an alternative approach?

**Note:** I need Spring to be managing the class (so other dependencies are injected) and other tests are needed for the same class using different test files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a setter. It's usually preferable to use setter injection instead of field injection anyhow. Even better, convert entirely to constructor and setter injection, and you can usually replace your Spring test context with mocks.

Comment: Thanks, I did briefly consider using a setter, the only thing that held me back was that we have used direct field injection everywhere else so it would be a slight case of breaking conventions and "changing the code to fit the test" - but think it may well be the best way.

Comment: @SteveChambers Fortunately, Spring makes it easy to migrate piecemeal from field injection, and not using it except in the odd case of configuration classes is a best practice.

Comment: Hi chrylis, your suggestion works, thanks! But what is the logic behind? Thanks mate.

Comment: @jumping_monkey Using constructor parameters or setters prevents the need for reflection, which is error-prone. It also allows you to make required fields final and prevents a whole class of NPEs that result from expecting external setting of private state.

Comment: Thanks a lot chrylis for your words of wisdom!

Answer (score 2):

Try [spring profiling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

Than you can switch profile for dev, prod, integration environments

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Value("${prop.name}")
    private String prop;


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }


    @Configuration
    @Profile("dev")
    @PropertySource("classpath:dev.properties")
    public static class DevAppConfig {
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("test")
    @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
    public static class TestAppConfig {
    }
}
```

Than in test use `@ActiveProfile("test")`

Comment: Thanks. Think the problem with this is there would have to be one configuration and properties file per test file - could get quite large/messy, especially if different combinations of other properties also needed to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand and agree